# Selecting an object inside a rectangle in Illustrator cc 2015

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, selections

I have created a rectangle shape inside which i have created several other shapes. I want to select one of these shapes, but as soon as I start drawing a marquee around this shape the rectangle moves and i am not able to select the object inside the rectangle.

Comment: When you say "inside", are these shapes actually inside (as in using the *draw inside* mode) or are they just on top of the rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways around it.

1) Inside layers panel, create new layer on top of the layer with your rectangle (which is going to be a backgdound, I presume) and then lock the layer containing the rectangle you wish to "avoid".

2) While your rectangle is selected press Ctrl + 2 (not F2, but number 2) this will "lock" anything you have selected currently and thus you won't be able to manipulate those objects. To "unlock" use combination of of Ctrl + Alt + 2.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, Basically I want to transfer all the content inside the rectangle to another layer so that i am rid of the rectangle and can select individual objects

Comment: Use layers panel, click in it's down-right corner to create a new layer and then drag all the objects you wish to transfer onto the new layer. Or just delete the rectangle that's causing you trouble.

Comment: Just deleting the rectangle did the trick . Many thanks